# How to stop Page Refrsh on javascript post

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I am creating a Flask application using html, css, flask and vanilla javascript as well as ajax.
I have 0 experience using Javascript and all the code I have written is from around the internet trying to piece together things.
I am creating a contact form where after the contact form is subitted I want the main contact form to dissapear and display a message:
The code itself works like it sends and email creates a new commit to the database but the whole page now does not refresh at all and wont display the 2nd div. shown bellow. The issues I am having is this. If I use  instead of a  the form requirments work but it does the refresh but if i use a button the form requirments dont work and but it does not refresh the page.
I am not so good at posting questions here on stack so if you have questions ask
example:

```
<form>
<div>
    <h2> main form </h2>
    <button type = "submit" onclick="saveContactForm();return false">Submit</button>
</div>
<form>
<div>
<h2> show after form submit>
</div>
```

My js is

```
function saveContactForm() {
    var formData = {
        name: $("input[name='name']").val(),
        email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
        subject: $("select[name='subject']").val(),
        message: $("textarea[name='message']").val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:  baseUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success: function (response) {
             autoReply(formData.email,formData.subject,formData.message)
                
           

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Email failed to send:', error);
        },
    });

}
function autoReply(email,subject,message) {
    let parms = {
        email: email,
        subject: subject,
        message: message 
    };
    service_id = secret;
    template_id = secret;
    public_key = secret;
    
    emailjs.send(service_id, template_id, parms, public_key).then(function(response) {
        document.querySelector(".container").style.display="none";
        document.querySelector(".back").style.display="flex";
    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.error('Email failed to send:', error);
    });
}
```

I am trying to have my submit button not refresh the page

Comment: you need to prevent the default action of submitting a form ... or don't use a form at all

Comment: The HTML above is invalid - there is no closing `form` tag (incorrectly used `<form>` again ) and there is a missing closing `h2` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.preventDefault()` at the top of the function `saveContactForm()`. So, it means that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

In the **button** **type='submit'**, it always tries to submit the form at the server level and refresh the page. So, to hold this default event call, you have to pass `event.preventDefault()` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `event` into `saveContactForm(event);` in button

```
<button type="submit" onclick="saveContactForm(event);return false">Submit</button>
```

and add event.preventDefault() into saveContactForm function

```
function saveContactForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var formData = {
        name: $("input[name='name']").val(),
        email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
        subject: $("select[name='subject']").val(),
        message: $("textarea[name='message']").val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success: function (response) {
            autoReply(formData.email, formData.subject, formData.message)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Email failed to send:', error);
        },
    });
}
```